# How to get jwt token generated by api to my app using HttpClient in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, httpclient

I have a working rest API that generates JWT token based on username and password.
URI:   http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate

This generates token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiLJKJJsaWNlbnNvciIsImV4cCI6MTYxNjQ0MjYyNiwiaWF0IjoxNjE2NDA2NjI2fQ.vPQZqiMgM6WzeJPKD8GV-91JIaHALVwMfLwTqXLRt8YLKnNUnOBKBUOYBh

I am using HttpClient to send request from my desktop application to my server. I want to send username and password from my desktop side and get the token generated above so that I can use it for other requests? How do i do it using HttpClient in java in code like below?

```
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST()
            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate"))
            .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ") // add request header
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please read [ask].

Comment: You might need to post more information on your setup etc. It depends on your identity provider but assuming it provides a service to get an access token you just need to call that with the correct credentials and get the token back (you might want to read up on OAuth flows - assuming it is OAuth). Note that you normally cannot get the same token as another application as that would be a security risk.

Comment: Look here for information on how to send the request for a JWT using basic authentication: https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, there is not enough information in the question.

The code below sends the username and password to your server and reads the response body and prints it out to the stdout (replace the username/password with the actual values) :

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String auth = "username:password";
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate"))
                .setHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();


        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println("response = " + response.body());

       }
    }
```